How to handle fromList method incompatibility with the Freezed package?
I was working with the Freezed package in Flutter, and I needed a method to convert a List into a model. I implemented a fromList factory method within the Freezed class. However, when running the build_runner, I encountered issues where the .g.dart files were not generated properly.
@freezed
abstract class SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel
    with _$SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel {
  factory SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel({
    // ignore: invalid_annotation_target
    @Default([])
    List<DormitoryRoomPicturesModel> dormitoryRoomPicturesItemsList,
  }) = _SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel;

  factory SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel.fromList(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    final roomPicturesList = jsonList
        .map((item) =>
            DormitoryRoomPicturesModel.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
    return SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel(
        dormitoryRoomPicturesItemsList: roomPicturesList);
  }
}

How can I define a fromList method for my Freezed class without causing conflicts with the code generation process?
.g.dart is expected to be generated correctly.

This problem occurs because the frozen package can handle the fromJson and toJson methods completely automatically, and if we want to use a separate customized method in a class created using the frozen package, it will cause inconsistencies in the .g.dart file generation.
To solve the problem, we need to remove our customized method, in this case the fromList method, from the frozen package and define it as a method outside our class:
@freezed
class SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel
    with _$SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel {
  factory SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel({
    @Default([]) List<DormitoryPicturesModel> dormitoryRoomPicturesItemsList,
  }) = _SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel;

  factory SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModelFromJson(json);
}


SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel succeedDormitoryRoomPicturesModelFromList(
    List<dynamic> jsonList) {
  final roomPicturesList = jsonList
      .map((item) =>
          DormitoryPicturesModel.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>))
      .toList();
  return SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel(
      dormitoryRoomPicturesItemsList: roomPicturesList);
}

Or we can define the same method as static inside our class without using a factory:
@freezed
class SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel
    with _$SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel {
  factory SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel({
    @Default([]) List<DormitoryPicturesModel> dormitoryRoomPicturesItemsList,
  }) = _SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel;

  factory SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModelFromJson(json);

  static SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel fromList(
      List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    final roomPicturesList = jsonList
        .map((item) =>
        DormitoryPicturesModel.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
    return SucceedDormitoryRoomPicturesModel(
        dormitoryRoomPicturesItemsList: roomPicturesList);
  }
}

